# NetBeans won't open

Tags: netbeans

When trying to open NetBeans, it seemingly started running, since i could see netbeans.exe in the TaskManager window. But, it never ended up opening anything, was just hanging there running, until i stopped it from the TaskManager.   It always worked before, until seeming to be after HP QuickTest Pro was installed on my laptop.

I tried rebooting my laptop, installed the latest netbeans 7.1.2, started it up from a different USERDIR, nothing helped and the same symptom.

The messages.log all showed one thing - the last line is

---

Loading HP QuickTest Professional Java Support (version 11.0.0.0) (SUN 1.7.0)

This seems to be the place where the netbeans was freezing....   My question is why netbeans startup try to load QuickTeste java?  how to stop it?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Yan Li

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall "HP QuickTest Professional Java Support (version 11.0.0.0) (SUN 1.7.0)"

Start NetBeans

If works then reinstall the HP*thing... or not if you dont need it...